# How to concatenate the values in R using loop function?

Tags: r

I want an output like this using a loop function:

```
> stat-1, stat-2, stat-3, stat4, stat5.
```

Currently this is my code:

```
x<-0;  
while (x <= 10)  

{  
  x <- x+1  
  z <- paste('stat-', x, collapse = "," ) 
  print(z) 
 }
```

But iam getting output like this:

```
[1] "stat- 1"  
[1] "stat- 2"  
[1] "stat- 3"  
[1] "stat- 4"  
[1] "stat- 5"
```

How can i get the output in single line?

Comment: You don't need a loop, `paste('stat_', x, collapse=",")` where `x <- 1:10`

Comment: Your output is not consistent with what you try to do. You certainly missed some "-". Could you correct for us to be certain of your desired output?

Comment: @akrun `collapse=", "` will insert a space after the comma.

Comment: to remove the space between the `-` and the number, use: `paste0('stat-', x, collapse = "," )`

Comment: The answer you choose doesn't match your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want several string you can also try :

```
x<-0;
z<-NULL; 
while (x <= 10)  {  
 x <- x+1  
 z <- c(z,paste('stat-', x, collapse = "," ))
}
print(z)
```

Comment: The OP would like a single line as output.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a `for` loop:

```
x <- 1:5

paste0("stat-", x, collapse = ", ")
# [1] "stat-1, stat-2, stat-3, stat-4, stat-5"
```

If you want a terminal ".":

```
paste0(paste0("stat-", x, collapse = ", "), ".")
# [1] "stat-1, stat-2, stat-3, stat-4, stat-5."
```